# Difference between wireless discarded packet metrics and netstat interface tx errors?

Tags: wifi, netstat

`cat /proc/net/wireless` on my system returns the following:

```
Inter-| sta-|   Quality        |   Discarded packets               | Missed | WE
 face | tus | link level noise |  nwid  crypt   frag  retry   misc | beacon | 22
 wlan0: 0000   39.  -71.  -256        0      0      0    456      0        0
```

The "retry" column gives the same value which is labelled as "Tx excessive retries" in the output of `iwconfig`.

In contract, `netstat -i` on the same system says:

```
Kernel Interface table
Iface      MTU    RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
wlan0     1500   387086      0      0 0        682507      0      0      0 BMRU
```

How is that the wireless stats says there have been 456 packets discarded due to "Tx excessive retries", but the `netstat -i` output for the same interface says no Tx packets have had errors or been dropped?

How should I understand these results?